# SQL update within same table based on summation

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-update, sum, duplicates

I have this table called t, as shown below.

```
   cust_id|    brand|    bill_amt|       AA|        BB|
   1234   |       AA|         100|     NULL|      NULL|
   5678   |       AA|         300|     NULL|      NULL|
   5678   |       BB|         350|     NULL|      NULL|
   5678   |       BB|         600|     NULL|      NULL|
```

I have around hundred thousands of records in my data, is there anyway I can update t table as shown below?

```
   cust_id|    brand|    bill_amt|       AA|        BB|
   1234   |       AA|         100|      100|      NULL|
   5678   |       AA|         300|      300|       950|
   5678   |       BB|         350|      300|       950|
   5678   |       BB|         600|      300|       950|
```

How can I show the bill_amt values under the AA and BB columns?
How can I sum up the bill_amt spent on the brand within the same customer? 
For example, looking at customer 5678, she spent $350 and $600 on different days for brand BB, how can I show in BB Column the summation of the bill_amt she spent for BB? 
Also, the same customer has spent $300 on AA, how can I show this value in the AA column?

Comment: did you consider using nested queries for summing up and updating the specified columns?

Comment: You only have two brands?

Comment: I have more than 2 brands, but just hoping to simplify the table shown above.

Comment: The question is. Why would you even consider this? Your db schema seems to be wrong because you are making a lot data redundancy when you should strive for avoiding duplication.  Why would you need to store aggregate amounts when you can calculate it at "runtime"? These aggregate amounts (or totals) don't even seem to belong to each record (row) because your records represent a financial transaction and the totals are not an attribute of each individual transaction.

Comment: There's no way to simplify it, except don't do it. You can get tehb running totals as a pivot / cross tab relatively easily, persisting them as a cross tab though is a really bad idea. In fact persisting any running total in the system that maintains the underlying data is at best a bodge. You are going to have to recalculate all of them all of the time anyway.

Comment: How did you generate the above table, for instance you mention that two purchases of BB happened on different dates, but date and purchase are nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the summary without actually creating a summary field in the table, you can simply use `OVER`; creating this as a view would most likely allow you the same advantages without altering the table.

```
SELECT CUST_ID, BRAND, BILL_AMT, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN brand='AA' THEN bill_amt ELSE NULL END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AA,
  SUM(CASE WHEN brand='BB' THEN bill_amt ELSE NULL END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) BB
FROM t;
```

To actually *update* the table, you can use a common table expression, however I'd *sincerely* advise against this except possibly for historical data that can never change, as changes to the data will no longer automatically update the summary.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN brand='AA' THEN bill_amt ELSE NULL END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) AA2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN brand='BB' THEN bill_amt ELSE NULL END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) BB2
  FROM t
) 
UPDATE cte SET AA=AA2, BB=BB2;
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing both ways](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e500/1).

Comment: Nice that, same problem as what I was going to post though, each brand = more sql.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes, you're right, I just read the comments above on more than 2 brands, was working from the viewpoint of the original question.

Comment: Me too , stopped now, especially seeing as your answer was better than mine anyway.